# Why is my query causing a 1064 (42000) error?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Query issues, for the life of me i cant figure out what is wrong with this query

```
HAVING distance  ='10'
GROUP BY c.ancient,
   c.ant_name,
   p.upper,
   p.name,
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP BY c.city_id, c.city_name,
>   p.prop_ynow_id, p.Name, pr.PRE_Ident
>   SELECT dis' at line 1

Comment: In your original post you had put 2 seemingly identical queries. I assume they just got pasted twice and that isn't what you were running?

Comment: that was the problem and the having..thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HAVING` goes after `GROUP BY`. MySQL is picky this way.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but Queries in any standard SQL from my experience generally have to go:

INSERT,
DELETE, 
SELECT,
FROM,
WHERE,
GROUP BY,
HAVING, ORDER BY

Order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do MySQL, but in the SQL I'm used to, the HAVING clause needs to go after the GROUP BY clause.